# What's the distribution of this random variable made of other variables?

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, density-function

I have $n$ random variables $X_i$, each following the same probability distribution but with different parameters. These variables can take only positive values.

Now, let's say I take one realization of each variable $[x_1, x_2, ..., x_n]$. I want to express a new variable $Y$ being the proportion of values in this vector which are inferior to 3 :
$$
Y = \dfrac{\# x_i \text{ such that } x_i \leq 3}{n},
$$

or

$$
Y = \dfrac{\sum \limits_{i=1}^n \mathbb{1}_{X_i \leq 3}}{n}.
$$

So how can I express $Y$ thanks to the distributions of each random variable $X_i$? I.e., what is the distribution of $Y$?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Not much you can simplify - you need to enumerate all of them. $\displaystyle \Pr\{Y = 0\} = \prod_{i=1}^n (1 - F_{X_i}(3))$, $\displaystyle \Pr\{Y = 1/n\} = \sum_{i=1}^n F_{X_i}(3) \prod_{j=1, j\neq i}^n (1 - F_{X_j}(3))$ and so on, until $\displaystyle \Pr\{Y = 1\} = \prod_{i=1}^n F_{X_i}(3)$

Comment: @BGM ... assuming the $X_i$ are independent

Comment: Sorry I miss that important assumption. I assumed they are independent, and even they are independent it is still messy.

Comment: "following the same probability distribution but with different parameters" is nonsense. It may be that the probability distributions of all of them are within some particular parametrized family of distributions, but that is true of every set of $n$ probability distributions. You should either be more explicit about what you're trying to say about their distributions, or else just say they have different distributions.

Comment: Thanks! 
@MichaelHardy yes I know but it's another problem I have, I'm not quite sure yet about their distribution because the $X_i$ are also depending on other random variables, I'll figure that out first